# How to add a new page to an existing HTML document with R flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a large R markdown script (first.Rmd) that generates an HTML file using flexdashboard

```
---
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard 
orientation: columns 
vertical_layout: scroll
---
```

I would like to add another page to this HTML but using another Rmd script (Second.Rmd) executed at a later stage.

If in the YAML of Second.Rmd I put

```
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    includes: 
      before_body: output.html
---
```

I just get a small blank square. If I write

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      before_body: output.html
---
```

it works better, the page appears where intended but it's content is shown at the bottom of every existing pages.

How to add another page the an existing HTML document?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you used `in_header: output.html` in the YAML? make sure you triple check your YAML indentation too, as sometimes that can cause unforeseen  render issues.[from Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html)

Comment: Using in_header give a similar result with both flex_dashboard (little blank square) and html_document (every page shows the new data).

Comment: You might need to use shiny, or a server to allow another web page to load. You could hyperlink them and host them both on http://www.rpubs.com You could have tabs in your flexdashboard, but that would still render 1 page. Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?